# WPF RichTextBox with Inline HTML - i18n

Tags: html, wpf, richtextbox, rtf

I have a RichTextBox which I'm trying to use to display a translateable block of text containing hyperlinks. The problem I'm having is I can't find a way to set the text property without manually coding the s and  controls into the content, which isn't translateable. Is there any way of doing this? I tried saving a simple RTF file containing one sentence using Word so I could extract the bits I need, but I end up with **160 lines** of difficult to decipher RTF text.

Ideally HTML would be easier but this doesn't seem to be supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ to parse out the anchors.

```
public static IEnumerable<Inline> ParseHtml(string text)
        {
            var inlines = new List<Inline>();
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(text);
            if(doc.ParseErrors==null ||!doc.ParseErrors.Any()) {
                foreach (var childNode in doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes) {
                    switch(childNode.Name.ToLowerInvariant()) {
                        case "a":
                            var lnk = new Hyperlink(new Run(childNode.InnerText));
                            lnk.NavigateUri = new Uri(childNode.Attributes["href"].Value);
                            inlines.Add(lnk);
                            break;
                        default:
                            inlines.Add(new Run(childNode.InnerText));
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return inlines;
        }
```